# Evaluate Integral $\int_{\frac{r}{2}}^{r}(e^{2t-2r}- e^{-2t})^{n-2} dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to  Evaluate Integral

> $\int_{\frac{r}{2}}^{r}(e^{2t-2r}- e^{-2t})^{n-2} dt$

the well known   way is to expand and then calculate the integral, but I am really interested finding another solutions

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint.

Changing variables $y = t-\frac r2$ we have $dt = dy$ and

$$
e^{2t-2r} - e^{-2t} = 4e^{-r}\cosh y\sinh y = 2\sinh(2y)e^{-r}
$$

then after that making $z = 2y$

$$
\frac{d}{dz}\left(\sinh^n z\cosh z\right) = (n+1)\sinh^{n+1}z + n \sinh ^{n-1}z
$$

now we can construct the recurrence formula

$$
(n+1)I_{n+1}+n I_{n-1} = \sinh^n z\cosh z|_a^b
$$

with

$$
I_n = \int_a^b \sinh^n z dz
$$

Comment: how can this be helpful

Comment: @Cesareo, Thanks, I guess we have problem  to find integral $\sinh^{n-2}(2y)$

Comment: @user62498 See the attached recurrence formula.